# Local images in NativeScript aren't showing up

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm just learning and have a very simple page right now. It's just this:

```
<GridLayout>
    <Label class="m-10 h3" verticalAlignment="top" [text]="team.fields.team.stringValue"></Label>
    <Image [src]="myImageSrc" stretch="none"></Image>
</GridLayout>
```

The source gets updated when I come into the page in the init function here:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.team = this.data.getHomeTeam();
    this.myImageSrc = "~/images/" + this.team.fields.team.stringValue + ".png";
}
```

And all of my images are present where I think they're supposed to be here:
[image]

But for some reason, this isn't working and nothing is showing up on the page when I go to it. For the life of me, I can't figure out why it's not, all of the examples I've seen use this exact method.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted? It's a legit issue I'm having so that's cool...

Comment: Can you inspect the "src" tag of the Image element with the chrome debug console element inspector?

Comment: It works just fine on my end, even just with `tns run [ios|android]` or  webpack + uglify + aot too. I'm running the latest CLI and runtime. Do you have a repo for sample project?

Comment: Did you try to set `width` and `height` on the image? You shouldn't be using a GridLayout like this, use a StackLayout if you don't want to provide columns and rows properties.

Comment: Code looks good to me. Try to print the image path on console and check if that image path actually exist. You can also refer to existing angular sample projects at https://market.nativescript.org/?tab=samples&framework=angular&category=all_samples

Answer (score 0):

Your images have whitespace in their name. It might be a problem. 
Have you tried to change their names, so instead of "My Image.png" name it "MyImage.png"? If you can't, how about adding ' to your source path, so it will treat that as the full path:

```
this.myImageSrc = "'~/images/" + this.team.fields.team.stringValue + ".png'";
```